# How to load dynamic data(Loaded from database) on a Pug(Jade) template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, pug

I have a invoice template created using Pug(Jade). Now the basic layout and all are done. What I need to do is load data from the database. There's also a data table too. Which loads all the items in the invoice. And also some simple values like customer name and all. Here's the Pug template I created. I am posting it as a github gist.

https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/eb54db78e300f6944ec7716238ee7d0c

Please check that. And this is the JavaScript function I'm using to render it and print it. Printing and all the stuff are fine.

```
api.get('/quotation_report/:id', function (req, res) {

    app.render('invoice', {
        quotation_no: 'Q0001',
        pump_no: 'P008!',
        number: parseInt(req.params.id)
    }, function (err, html) {

        var html1 = html;
        var options = {format: 'A4'};

        pdf.create(html1, options).toFile('./invoice.pdf', function (err, response) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(response);

            var file = fs.createReadStream('./invoice.pdf');
            var stat = fs.statSync('./invoice.pdf');
            res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=invoice.pdf');
            file.pipe(res);
        });
    });

});
```

In here, check 'app.render.......' function. I know we can send object arrays and variables in there. But how to send an arrays and how to use them in Pug template ?

Here's the image of my invoice.

[image]

The quotation no , pump no , se no and all are in a single object. And all the items in a json array. So how can I access them in Pug Template ? And how to send those arrays and objects from the javascript function to Pug template ?